# how to display ad banner (buzzcity) in cocos2d project?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, admob, eaglview, adbannerview

is there a way to put `UIView` by converting it to `EAGLView` or should i have to add `CAlayer` ?
whats the best way to do it?
any Example codes related to `BuzzCity` for `Cocos2d` would be nice

what i have found till now----

```
btnAD = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"underwater-images-paradox-visual-wallpapers-title-search-196522.jpg" selectedImage:@"underwater-images-paradox-visual-wallpapers-title-search-196522.jpg" target:self selector:@selector(AdbuttonAction)];
btnAD.position=ccp(0, 0);
```

what i am trying is to display ad on button image...
and call the url for ad on **buttonAction**
how to display this button on top of my `uiview`?

**documentation** of buzzCity ad integration 
http://docs.buzzcity.net/wiki/IOS_SDK#Advanced_Integration_using_BuzzCity_iOS_SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not sandwich UIViews between two cocos nodes. If you want an ad button, display the ad as background of a UIButton, or simply make the ad "touchable" by testing if touch location is within ad's frame.

Comment: done. now i can display image from my bundle as background image for my ccmenuitem. problem is with itemFromNormalImage needs nsstring not uiimage

Answer (score 0):

first i saved my image to documents directory

```
- (NSString *)saveImage {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://ads.buzzcity.net/show.php?partnerid=8404&browser=app_apple"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
      //convert image into .png format.
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImage"];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"image saved");
    return fullPath;

}
```

then i added that path to `**itemFromNormalImage:fullPath**`

```
NSString *fullPath=[self saveImage];
    btnAD = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:fullPath selectedImage:fullPath target:self selector:@selector(AdButtonAction)];

        NSLog(@"btnAD %@", btnAD);

    CCMenu *adMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:btnAD, nil];
    [self addChild:adMenu];
    adMenu.position = ccp(350 ,size.height-50);
```

finally on button action open the url

```
-(void)AdButtonAction
{
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://click.buzzcity.net/click.php?partnerid=8404&browser=app_apple"];
  NSLog(@"url = %@",url);
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```